# Spivak's Calculus 8-8(a)

Tags: real-analysis

This question is from Calculus by Spivak, Chapter 8 on Least Upper Bounds:

> Suppose that $f$ is a function such that $f(a) \leq f(b)$ whenever $a<b$.  Prove that $\lim_{x_\to a^-} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x_\to a^+} f(x)$  both exist.

Worked on it for a while but didn't get anywhere.   Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @ClementC.  Thanks but I still don't know how to prove that delta exists such that the limit is the supremum of the set where ${f(x):x<a}$

Answer (score 4):

Fix $a$ in the domain of $f$  Then $\left \{ f(x):x\le a \right \}$ is bounded above by $f(a)$ and so has a least upper bound, $A\le f(a).$

By definition of $A$ as the $\textit{least}$ upper bound, if $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta >0$ such that if $x\in (a-\delta,a), $ then $A-f(x)<\epsilon,\ $ which says precisely that $f(a^-)=A$.

Similarly, you can show that $f(a^+)=\inf \left \{ f(x):x\ge a \right \}.$

Comment: It seems I'm missing a piece of understanding about least upper bound.  Why exactly is your second sentence true?  In particular why does it work for any $\epsilon$?  I can't link the basic definition of least upper bound to your statement.  Isn't it possible that we choose $\epsilon$ too small for such conditions to hold?

Comment: It's the definition of least upper bound. If the statement is NOT true then $A$ is easily seen not to be the least upper bound of the set.